# Auto Complete Textbox using angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My Textbox look like this..

```
 <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : 
  TicketSupportForm.TicketNo.$invalid && !TicketSupportForm.TicketNo.$pristine }">
 <input type="text" ng-keyup="Autocomplete(TicketNo)" class="form-control" id="txtTicketNo" placeholder="Ticket Number"
 name="TicketNo" ng-model="TicketNo" required>
 </div>
```

Js Code Here

```
$scope.Autocomplete = function (id) {
    debugger
    $http.get("/api/TicketSupport/GetTicketIDForAutoComplete?TransID=" + id)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          if (data != "") {
              //console.log(data[0].TransID);
              $("#txtTicketNo").autocomplete({
                  status: data[0].TransID
              });
          }
      });
}
```

In above Code "GetTicketIDForAutoComplete" function get the data from the DB.
data[0].TransID also get values..
But It shows an error "AutoComplete" is not a function

I already added js tags also

```
     <link rel="stylesheet"   href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this one,

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/][1]
```

In Material design you can create stylish autocomplete textbox
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete